# ruby in rails Error while confirming email in devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, ruby-on-rails-5

i'm using devise on rails5 to confirm email address for login. everything works well until i click the confirmation link. then it shows me this error:

> NameError in Devise::ConfirmationsController#show
>
> undefined local variable or method `signin' for #< Class:0x007fb1cbe56b48>

this is the code that causes the error:

```
        conditions = warden_conditions.dup
        where(conditions).where(["lower(username) = :value OR lower(email)
            = :value", { :value => signin.downcase }]).first

end
```

this is my model that the above code belongs to:

```
devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :confirmable
attr_accessor :signin

validates :username, :uniqueness => {:case_sensitive => false}

def self.find_first_by_auth_conditions(warden_conditions)
    conditions = warden_conditions.dup
        where(conditions).where(["lower(username) = :value OR   lower(email)
            = :value", { :value => signin.downcase }]).first
end
```

can some one help me about it? and if you give me some information about how this method works?

Comment: At first glance I would say it has to do with the signin attr_accessor. What do you do with it ?

Comment: just using it to signin

Comment: It would be better to do the sign in using a helper method rather than an attr_accessor because they don't live long.

Comment: ok but how can writing a helper, helps with my current problem?

Comment: undefined local variable or method `signin' means that your attr_accessor is not defined. This might be because of its short life span. I had a similar problem when I tried to work with facebook and twitter oauth. I used an attr_accesor to bypass the validation for these users but when I tried to reference it later is gave me the same error. That is why I don't like attr_accessor.

Comment: so how can i write this helper?

Comment: and when i use this attr_accessor for sign in regularly it works. but when it comes from confirmation email link it doesn't. i can feel that there is sth wrong with this part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing, `attr_accessor` defines an instance method, not a class method, so if you call `signin` inside a class method like `self.find_first_by_auth_conditions` is going to throw you that `undefined local variable or method 'signin' for #< Class:0x007fb1cbe56b48>` error.

Second, your `find_for_database_authentication` method is incomplete. You should base according to [this example](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Allow-users-to-sign-in-using-their-username-or-email-address#overwrite-devises-find_for_database_authentication-method-in-user-model):

```
def self.find_for_database_authentication(warden_conditions)
  conditions = warden_conditions.dup
  if login = conditions.delete(:login)
    where(conditions.to_h).where([
      "lower(username) = :value OR lower(email) = :value", 
      { :value => login.downcase }
    ]).first
  elsif conditions.has_key?(:username) || conditions.has_key?(:email)
    where(conditions.to_h).first
  end
end
```

I'm not sure if you already used that example as base, but if you explain what were your reasons to modify it, it would be great. I there's no reasons, use that piece of code.

Comment: this worked. the code that i've used is from a book about devise which is a bit outdated thats why i have got confused about it, and i'm still a beginner in rails which i think is the reason i wasn't able to modify it myself. thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I post my answere to your comment here. I don't know how you handle sign in but the way I did it was in the Session Controller and Session Helper:

```
#Session Controller

 def create
    user = User.find_by(email: params[:session][:email].downcase)
    if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:email].downcase)
      log_in user
      redirect_back_or user
      flash[:success] = "You are logged in"
    else
      flash[:danger] = "Wrong email or password"
      render 'new'
    end
  end
```

The "log_in(user)" method that I used is defined in the Session Helper.

```
#Session Helper

  def log_in(user)
    session[:user_id] = user.id
  end
```

Comment: ok but this is not what im looking for because im using devise to sign in

Comment: It gives you an idea of what you can do.